# writing a local application for iOS

Tags: ios

I'm about to write an application for a specific organization, which don't want to publish their app in appSotre.
as much as I know, the only way to do this is by ad hoc, limited for 100 users.

do I have any alternative/s?

Comment: Look into Enterprise developer program. You can create In-house distribution certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can distribute organization-specific applications using Apple's Enterprise Distribution Program: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: thanks... does the app needs to be approved by apple?

Comment: No, you're not required to submit the app to Apple for approval. However, keep in mind that Apple does need to approve your request for an enterprise account, so be sure that you're actually using the program as intended and not as a means to circumvent the normal App Store (i.e. the app should not be distributed outside of your organization).